# r - How can I extract multiple lines of text between two symbols?

Tags: r

Sorry, I am new with R, so this might be a basic question.

Say I have a text file that looks like this:

```
START1 
<line1>
    <line2>
<line3>
END1

START2
<line4>
    <line5>
<line6>
END2
```

And I want to save two objects, TEXT1 and TEXT2, that look like this:

TEXT1:

```
<line1>
    <line2>
<line3>
```

TEXT 2:

```
<line4>
    <line5>
<line6>
```

So basically, I want a script that will select all the line between two symbols and preserve the formatting.

I tried using gsub like this:

```
TEXT1 <- gsub(".*START1 | END1.*", "", x)
```

but it seems like gsub will only work for a string, not for multiple lines and keeping the formatting.

Any ideas?

Comment: `x <- strsplit('START1 
<line1>
         <line2>
         <line3>
         END1
         
         START2
         <line4>
         <line5>
         <line6>
         END2', '\\s*(START\\d+|END\\d+)\\s*')[[1]]; x <- x[x != '']`

Comment: But this results in the same problem. The formatting is lost in the process

Comment: If you define `x` by copying from above, it will keep it. It won't look like it though; you need to print the results with `cat` to display newlines and such properly.

Answer (score 2):

Sinnce you say you have a file,   perhaps read with something like `text = readLines("myfile.txt")`, then `text` will be a vector. Below code  filters the lines that do not have start and end. This

```
text[!grepl("(START\\d+|\\s*END\\d+)", text)]
```